# Proving three people must be mutually friends, enemies, or strangers

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

> There are $17$ people in a room. Every two people are mutually
>   friends, enemies, or strangers. Prove there must be three people all
>   of whom have the same relationship.

I think this is a graph coloring problem. It is a problem from my book but I am struggling to solve it. I tried to do many things, like considering the chromatic polynomial of the graph. But I have had no luck. I am really not sure how to approach the problem and will appreciate any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that every edge-coloring of $K_{17}$ with 3 colors contains a monochromatic $K_3$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754910/prove-that-every-edge-coloring-of-k-17-with-3-colors-contains-a-monochroma)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the graph of relationships is $K_{17}$. This is an edge-coloring exercise. Note that any given vertex $v$ is connected to $16$ other vertices, so by the pigeonhole principle and without loss of generality, $v$ has at least $6$ friends. Note that these $6$ friends can't be friends with each other.

Consider the subgraph of $6$ vertices of these friends and all of their relationships (either stranger or enemy). Consider vertex $w$. By pigeonhole and WLOG, $w$ has at least $3$ enemies. These three enemies must all be strangers with each other, which is a contradiction, so we are done.

Comment: "By pigeonhole and WLOG, $w$ has at least $3$ enemies." Why is this true?

Comment: $5$ neighbors, which are either enemies or strangers. If there are $2$ or less enemies, there are $3$ or more strangers, so rename strangers to enemies and continue.

Comment: Why is it true that the three enemies must all be strangers with each other?

Comment: If any two of the three enemies are enemies, then those two and $w$ form an enemy triangle.