# Proving $R(3,3,3)\le17$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory

I've been working on some problems in my introductory discrete mathematics
course, and I am trying to figure out a proof that $R(3,3,3) \leq 17.$ I
initially consider an instance where we have a $K_{17}$ colored in the arbitrary
colors $c_1,c_2,c_3$. Consider a vertex $v \in K_{17}.$ It should have 16
edges coming out of it, so by the pigeonhole principle, it should have 6 edges
coming out of it that are colored in one color. Without loss of generality,
we can say that these are colored $c_1$. Consider these $c_1$ adjacent
vertices $v_1,...,v_6$. If there is a $c_1$ colored edge between any one of
them, we are done. Otherwise, I am not entirely sure what I can do with 6
vertices whose colors are arbitrary colored $c_2$ or $c_3$. Any recommendations
for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since $R(3,3)=6$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example:_R.283.2C_3.29_.3D_6)), if there are six vertices colored only with $c_2$ and $c_3$, then you have a monochromatic triangle.

This is the same proof that $R(3,3,3)\le17$ which is described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#A_multicolour_example:_R.283.2C_3.2C_3.29_.3D_17) and in answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935143/chromatic-triangles-on-a-k17-graph). And you will probably find it in [many other places](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22R+3+3+3+17%22+ramsey).